# For each loop with labels and variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggeling realising a userform I do have several labels named "l_MBout", "l_MBin", "l_Fin" and many more. The values for the captions are stored in variables called "MBout", "MBin", "LFin" and so on (These are calculated integers -- always named like the corresponding labels but without the "l_"). My idea was to define an array for the labels

```
Public labelarray As Variant
labelarray = Array("l_MBin", "l_MBout", "l_Gin", "l_Gout", "l_Fin", "l_Fout", "l_DLZMB", "l_DLZG", "l_DLZF")
```

and use something like this to write the values from the variables to the Labels (removing the front "l_")

```
Public lbl As Variant

For Each lbl In labelarray
    If Right(lbl, Len(lbl) - 2) > 0 Then
        Managementsitzung.Controls(lbl & i1).Caption = Right(lbl, Len(lbl) - 2)
    Else
        Managementsitzung.Controls(lbl & i1).Caption = "-"
    End If
Next lbl
```

but it seems the

```
Right(lbl, Len(lbl) - 2)
```

is not linked to the variable (my guess it is still a string)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is `i1` and are there controls on your form with the name `l_Mbout & i1`? So, if `i1 = "someName"` then there must be controls with the name `l_MBinsomeName`, `l_MBoutsomeName`, `l_GinsomeName`, etc.

Comment: the "i1" is coming from another loop (3 rows of labels) ... anyway, found a solution (see below). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. All `Right(lbl, Len(lbl) - 2)` is is a string, not a variable. May I suggest making two parallel arrays so you can hold both the labels and the variables.

```
labelarray = Array("l_MBin", "l_MBout", "l_Gin", "l_Gout", "l_Fin", "l_Fout", ...
valarray = Array(Mbin, MBout, Gin, Gout, Fin, Fout, ...
```

Then you can loop through the labels, but do a check on the values.

```
For i=lbound(labelarray) to ubound(labelarray)
    If valarray(i) > 0 Then
        Managementsitzung.Controls(labelarray(i) & i1).Caption = valarray(i)     
    Else
        Managementsitzung.Controls(labelarray(i) & i1).Caption = "-"
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the label *objects* in the array, not their names:

```
Option Explicit
Private labelarray As Variant

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    labelarray = Array(l_MBin, l_MBout, l_Gin, l_Gout, l_Fin, l_Fout, l_DLZMB, l_DLZG, l_DLZF)
End Sub
```

Then you can access their properties in your loop:

```
Dim lbl As Variant

For Each lbl In labelarray
    With lbl
        If Right(.Name, Len(.Name) - 2) > 0 Then
            .Caption = Right(.Name, Len(.Name) - 2)
        Else
            .Caption = "-"
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: @Moritz - Your loss ;-)